# Forcing heading tags to be sequential with DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, wordpress, accessibility, domdocument

We build bespoke WordPress themes, and recently have been receiving complaints regarding the sequence of headings. Most automated tools, including Google's Lighthouse, suggest that you should never skip heading levels, in order to properly communicate page structure for screen readers and other accessibility tools.

This issue is largely due to the way our clients enter content. They tend to prefer picking a visually pleasing heading, rather than the "correct" heading sequentially, so we'll often end up with pages that have an h1, then an h4, then a set of h2s, and so on. We've told these clients that they can fix this by properly entering content, but this seems to be asking too much of them, much like entering alt text for images.

To "solve" this issue, I'm trying to write a filter that will parse `the_content`, identify all of the headings, and replace their tags so that they become sequential, retaining classes for styling. I realize that this isn't a perfect solution, as the intended heading structure really can't be assumed programmatically, but this is the only viable solution I've been able to determine (if someone has a better idea, please, do tell).

So, for example, the code the user generates could be something like this:

```html
<h2 class="title--h2">This is a second level heading</h2>

<p>Etiam vitae erat ullamcorper ipsum ultrices convallis ac quis nulla. Nam euismod imperdiet enim eu venenatis. Nulla non bibendum dui. Maecenas id tincidunt orci. Sed pellentesque ipsum et tempor convallis. Etiam elementum augue aliquet enim venenatis tincidunt. Praesent nunc dolor, vulputate nec aliquet consectetur, aliquet nec elit. Vivamus non eros nec nibh vestibulum lacinia. Morbi diam turpis, accumsan ac fringilla eget, fringilla vitae lorem. Ut consequat tortor orci, sed lobortis metus facilisis nec. Nulla sed enim in tortor blandit aliquet. Curabitur a finibus mi.</p>

<h4 class="title--h4">This is a fourth level heading</h4>

<p>Nullam blandit, mauris vel vestibulum aliquet, quam lectus laoreet mi, id euismod ligula augue sit amet velit. Suspendisse suscipit lacus quis mauris varius, sed cursus mi auctor. Nullam non augue in ante malesuada blandit. Nam eu purus commodo, porttitor odio commodo, tristique nunc. Suspendisse vitae vehicula turpis. Aenean turpis nibh, auctor ac mollis congue, iaculis id tortor. Morbi in est erat. Proin aliquam varius neque a sollicitudin. Vestibulum varius in urna sit amet hendrerit.</p>

<h4 class="title--h4">This is a fourth level heading</h4>

<p>Donec vitae est sapien. Nulla facilisi. Quisque sed auctor ante, sed viverra elit. Quisque justo arcu, vulputate tempor odio ac, mollis blandit justo. Morbi viverra tincidunt leo vel mattis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc tortor tellus, porta sit amet tellus sed, interdum condimentum ex. </p>
```

And the output would be:

```html
<h2 class="title--h2">This is a second level heading</h2>

<p>Etiam vitae erat ullamcorper ipsum ultrices convallis ac quis nulla. Nam euismod imperdiet enim eu venenatis. Nulla non bibendum dui. Maecenas id tincidunt orci. Sed pellentesque ipsum et tempor convallis. Etiam elementum augue aliquet enim venenatis tincidunt. Praesent nunc dolor, vulputate nec aliquet consectetur, aliquet nec elit. Vivamus non eros nec nibh vestibulum lacinia. Morbi diam turpis, accumsan ac fringilla eget, fringilla vitae lorem. Ut consequat tortor orci, sed lobortis metus facilisis nec. Nulla sed enim in tortor blandit aliquet. Curabitur a finibus mi.</p>

<h3 class="title--h4">This is a fourth level heading</h3>

<p>Nullam blandit, mauris vel vestibulum aliquet, quam lectus laoreet mi, id euismod ligula augue sit amet velit. Suspendisse suscipit lacus quis mauris varius, sed cursus mi auctor. Nullam non augue in ante malesuada blandit. Nam eu purus commodo, porttitor odio commodo, tristique nunc. Suspendisse vitae vehicula turpis. Aenean turpis nibh, auctor ac mollis congue, iaculis id tortor. Morbi in est erat. Proin aliquam varius neque a sollicitudin. Vestibulum varius in urna sit amet hendrerit.</p>

<h4 class="title--h4">This is a fourth level heading</h4>

<p>Donec vitae est sapien. Nulla facilisi. Quisque sed auctor ante, sed viverra elit. Quisque justo arcu, vulputate tempor odio ac, mollis blandit justo. Morbi viverra tincidunt leo vel mattis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc tortor tellus, porta sit amet tellus sed, interdum condimentum ex. </p>
```

Again, I realize this is going to lead to unintended structure (I included an example of this in the above demonstration), but this is what my clients are asking for, so I'm giving in.

The code I have so far will track the previous heading level and determine what the new level should be, but I'm having difficulty understanding how to actually replace the tags correctly. My understanding is that modifying the DOM with `$node->replaceChild()` is going to result in items getting skipped, because the DOM is changing while its being parsed. Additionally, I'd like to retain *all* attributes on each heading, but I've been unable to locate a method for this; everything suggests copying individual attributes manually, but because this is CMS-driven, I'm worried that custom or unexpected attributes will be missed.

Here's the filter I have so far:

```php
/**
 * Ensure heading levels are always in sequence
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return string
 */
function namespace_fix_title_sequence(string $content): string {
    if (! (is_admin() && ! wp_doing_ajax()) && $content) {
        $DOM = new DOMDocument();

        /**
         * Use internal errors to get around HTML5 warnings
         */
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        /**
         * Load in the content, with proper encoding and an `<html>` wrapper required for parsing
         */
        $DOM->loadHTML("<?xml encoding='utf-8' ?><html>{$content}</html>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

        /**
         * Clear errors to get around HTML5 warnings
         */
        libxml_clear_errors();

        /**
         * Use XPath to query headings
         */
        $XPath = new DOMXPath($DOM);

        $headings = $XPath->query("//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::h5 or self::h6]");

        /**
         * Track previous heading level
         */
        $previous_level = 1;

        foreach ($headings as $heading) {
            /**
             * Get the current level
             */
            $current_level = intval(preg_replace("/^h/", "", $heading->nodeName));

            /**
             * Determine the target level
             */
            $target_level = ($current_level - $previous_level <= 1 ? $current_level : $previous_level + 1);

            /**
             * DEBUG
             */
            echo "<p>Previous: {$previous_level}</p>";
            echo "<p>Current: {$current_level}</p>";
            echo "<p>Target: {$target_level}</p>";
            echo "<hr />";

            /**
             * Replace current level with target level
             */
            // ?

            /**
             * Update the previous level
             */
            $previous_level = $target_level;
        }

        /**
         * Save changes, remove unneeded tags
         */
        $content = implode(array_map([$DOM->documentElement->ownerDocument, "saveHTML"], iterator_to_array($DOM->documentElement->childNodes)));
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter("the_content", "namespace_fix_title_sequence", 100, 1);
```

Comment: In your example, you change the first `h4` to an `h3` because it's after an `h2` but you didn't change the second `h4`. What if the second one has the same "level" of information as the first one. How do you decide whether both headings should be changed to `h3`?  Unfortunately, you're probably in a lose-lose situation because no matter what you do, you'll be wrong in many cases.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to have a main `h1` then an `h2` then maybe some `h3`s in the footer to organize the footer links, although the `h3`s in the footer aren't "nested" under the previous `h2`. And then you might have another page with a main `h1` but no `h2` but still have the `h3`s in the footer links. If you run your tool to change the footer headings to `h2`s, you'd be creating an accessibility issue, [3.2.4 Consistent Identification](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#consistent-identification), because now you'd have similar information on different pages at different heading levels.

Comment: @slugolicious yeah, this is what I've tried to explain time and time again, but they won't listen to me, and just want an automated solution to fix the "problem." I completely agree this isn't ideal, and really creates more confusion, I'm just trying to put this to rest so I can stop arguing about it, lol...

Answer (score 1):

#### The ideal unrealistic solution

In an ideal world, the best solution would be to totally prevent the content writer from selecting incorrect heading levels in the interface of their WYSIWYG.
As equally as you should maybe force them to put a non-empty alt text for images, a label for input fields, forbid empty links, etc.

Given some place in the document, they would only be allowed to put an heading of level 1 to N+1 where N is the level of the previous heading.

Consider that adjustments would also possibly have to be propagated, i.e. changing an H3 into an H2 in the middle of the text should also change all the following H4 into H3 down to the next H2, and so recursively.
This is, as you see, not as easy as we may think at first.

Sadly, not only it isn't that easy, neither to develop and to use, but anyway, writers are probably not ready for that. Those who don't understand the need for correct structuration will also probably qualify the restriction as a bug or a stupid software limitation against their freedom to write anything in the way they like.
Maybe you could decorelate heading level from the corresponding visual style to avoid frustration, but it's becoming quickly even more complicated.

So the only thing that you can do is educate content writers, or, just as you are proposing it here, trying to fix the incorrect structure automatically.

#### Algorithm to fix heading structure

Before getting more in the real taslk of DOM manipulation, let's talk a little about an algorithm. It's of course impossible to always fix the stucture in the way the author wanted it to be 100% of the time, but the goal is still trying to choose the most probable thing the author wanted to do.

IF we take your example back, the author wrote H2, H4, H3, H3. Is the simplest fix, H2, H3, H3, H3 the most appropriate?
What about H2, H3, H4, H4? Based on the fact that if two elements are visually different, it was probably intended that they are at different levels, and conversely, if two elements are visually identical, it was also probably intended that they are on the same level.

#### DOM maipulation

As far as I know, most DOM API  I have ever seen in Java, JavaScript, PHP, C++, etc. effectively don't allow you to directly change the element name in place. You must create a new node to do that.
You can't simply change an H4 into an H3 while retaining the inner structure untouched for example.
So, if you indeed can't change the element name in place, you need to:

1. Create a fragment F with the inner structure of the H4 you want to change into H3.
   If fragments are also unavailable or if extracting a fragment is complicated in the DOM API you are using, you have to clone child nodes one by one in an array.
2. Create the H3 node and put F into it
3. Copy attributes of the H4 into the H3. There is probably no other way than to make it one by one.
4. Replace the H4 by the new H3. Alternatively, if there is no replaceChild method, insert the H3 before the H4 and then remove the H4.

Comment: Thanks, all of this is exactly what I've tried telling people, but for years, I keep getting this question, so I'm just trying to silence it. People just see an automated test spit out an "error" and want an "automatic" fix, no matter how impractical it is. I'll try relying some of this information in a concise way, maybe we just need to make a post on our company blog going over all of this to direct clients to...